# Using [Chat] in comments while being in Meta shouldn't display "Site X Meta Chat"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, hyperlinks

I just used the magic `[chat]` abbreviation that automatically points to Chat. But while on the Main site I get **Linguistics Chat**, using the same code in Meta displays **Linguistics Meta Chat**.

**Main**:

> [image: Linguistics Main]

**Meta**:

> [image]

This is not a really bad problem, but it's kind of misleading since sites, apart from SO/MSO, do not have a default separate main chat room. Unless I'm missing something, I think we should keep the same wording for both Main and Meta.

Comment: What happens when you click on "Linguistics Meta Chat"? Is it just the wording of the link that's changed?

Comment: @TheEstablishment It gets me to `http://chat.stackexchange.com/` too. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good catch, fixed in the next build.

Comment: Cool. :) [chat] ops!